# How can I validate text as being valid HTML?

Tags: asp.net, html, validation, telerik, radeditor

I'm using an older version of [Telerik's](http://www.telerik.com/) [Editor](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx) control, and storing the text that's input in a SQL database, then displaying the HTML later. Is there any way in ASP.NET (2.0) to validate a string as being valid HTML before saving to my database? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start here:

[C# XHTML Validator](http://dotnetperls.com/xhtml-validator)

Or here (regexes):

[Regular Expressions Library - entries tagged with "HTML"](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=html+tags&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20)

Or here ;)

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=c%23+validate+html&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)

Comment: That validates XHTML which can be a little more strict.

Answer (score 0):

regexes can be slow and cpu intensive, W3C has an open source tool that you could use http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/

Answer (score 0):

The editor has a built-in validator dialog that connects to the online W3 tool to check the current content. You can see an example here - [XHTML Validator example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/xhtmlvalidatortrackchangesformatcodeblockdialogs/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - which version are you using ("older version" isn't terribly specific)?

In the .Net 1.1/2.0 versions (I think about version 3.x/4.x from 2004/2005) the editor API consisted of a read/write property `Html` that allowed you to set the content as HTML, and also retrieve it for storing where ever, and a *read only* property `Xhtml` that ensures the you get compliant, XML based content (there were also properties like `SaveAsXhtml` to ensure that if you were writing back to the file, it would be in XHTML).

I appreciate that if your page is serving content to HTML 4.0 then you might have some issues with closed tags (`<br />`, `<img />`, etc).

Remember there's a difference between valid HTML and clean HTML.

I see that the [current version](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/telerik.web.ui-telerik.web.ui.radeditor_members.html) no longer has an `Xhtml` property, and that the `Html` property is deprecated in favour of the `Content` property, so I assume this is outputting valid Xhtml by default.