# jQuery to validate HTML in a TextArea

Tags: jquery, validation, textarea

I have a TextArea which allows the user to enter HTML, what I am now trying to do is to validate the users HTML to ensure it is XHTML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a DOM Parser to see if the content is XML.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_parser.asp).

---

SNIPPET:

```
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
  }
```

Comment: var error =$(xmlDoc.documentElement).find('parsererror').first();
    if(error) ...


Something like this will tell you if there is an error and a not very helpful error as `error.text()`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using regular expressions.
Start at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435650/how-can-i-validate-text-as-being-valid-html)

I havent seen a jquery plugin that does exactly what you want itself, but i'm sure you can alter some existing validation.

Comment: *cough* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454